# Android Program wont start after name change

Tags: java, android, eclipse

why is my app crashing. I tried to change a name and now it doesn't work. Here is the log file.

```
08-07 09:09:35.112: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(310): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
08-07 09:09:35.112: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(310): CheckJNI is ON
08-07 09:09:35.272: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(310): --- registering native functions ---
08-07 09:09:35.912: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(310): Shutting down VM
08-07 09:09:35.912: DEBUG/dalvikvm(310): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-07 09:09:35.932: INFO/AndroidRuntime(310): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-07 09:09:36.392: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(318): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
08-07 09:09:36.392: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(318): CheckJNI is ON
08-07 09:09:36.542: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(318): --- registering native functions ---
08-07 09:09:37.172: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.marcus.guessingletters uid=10044
08-07 09:09:37.172: INFO/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 303 SIG: 9
08-07 09:09:37.212: INFO/UsageStats(59): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.marcus.guessingletters
08-07 09:09:37.332: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.marcus.guessingletters/.Game }
08-07 09:09:37.332: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(318): Shutting down VM
08-07 09:09:37.342: DEBUG/jdwp(318): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
08-07 09:09:37.342: DEBUG/dalvikvm(318): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-07 09:09:37.382: INFO/AndroidRuntime(318): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-07 09:09:37.663: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.marcus.guessingletters for activity com.marcus.guessingletters/.Game: pid=325 uid=10044 gids={3003, 1015}
08-07 09:09:37.833: WARN/ActivityThread(325): Application com.marcus.guessingletters is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
08-07 09:09:37.862: INFO/System.out(325): Sending WAIT chunk
08-07 09:09:37.862: INFO/dalvikvm(325): Debugger is active
08-07 09:09:38.112: INFO/System.out(325): Debugger has connected
08-07 09:09:38.112: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:38.312: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:38.522: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:38.736: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:38.945: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:39.142: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:39.342: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:39.586: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:39.798: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:40.004: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:40.210: INFO/System.out(325): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-07 09:09:40.416: INFO/System.out(325): debugger has settled (1451)
08-07 09:09:45.122: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(59): pokeWakelock(5000)
08-07 09:09:45.402: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(59): pokeWakelock(5000)
08-07 09:09:45.662: INFO/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x398dc0:0x398ecc] in 807118 ns
08-07 09:09:45.722: INFO/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x398ed0:0x399098] in 873416 ns
08-07 09:09:47.384: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-07 09:09:47.864: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450bbd70 com.marcus.guessingletters/.Game}
08-07 09:09:53.013: DEBUG/dalvikvm(126): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1636 objects / 82768 bytes in 144ms
08-07 09:11:45.932: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: did you change the Activity class name? You have to put every activity in you manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should check you manifest.xml file. And yes project clean is a must. i faced the same problem today as yours.

Answer (score 0):

As jernej said, try to check AndroidManifest.xml for consistence. You can also try a full uninstall of previous application and a clean of actual project (project > clean)